# How to upload multiple images to Cloudinary?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, cloudinary

I've implemented a working post route that uploads a single image to cloudinary on submit.

What needs to be changed to enable multiple image upload? Any help is appreciated.

**My post route:**

```
app.post("/portfolio/new", upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        req.body.image = result.secure_url;
        console.log(req.body.image);

        Portfolio.create(req.body.project, function(err, newProject) {]
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.redirect("/portfolio");
        });
    });
});
```

**My HTML (with EJS):**

```
<form action="/portfolio/new" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <div>
        Select images: 
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*" required>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: follow this tutorial [https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-upload-multiple-images-using-cloudinary-and-node-js-2f053b167b80](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-upload-multiple-images-using-cloudinary-and-node-js-2f053b167b80)

Comment: @turivishal Thank you for the article link but I don't have enough experience to restructure the code in this guide to fit my needs. The author describes how this can be done as a standalone node app rather than a familiar html form post route. I tried to do it but am making many mistakes and no progress.

Comment: Hey @Ian, You can start from basic, watch video tutorials and refer stack overflow questions and make demos, please post your another question as new question in stack overflow because you will get more answers from many stack overflow contributors..

Answer (score 4):

```
    const cloudinaryImageUploadMethod = async file => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          cloudinary.uploader.upload( file , (err, res) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send("upload image error")
              resolve({ 
                res: res.secure_url
              }) 
            }
          ) 
      })
    }
    
    router.post("/", upload.array("img", 3 ), async (req, res) => {

        const urls = [];
        const files = req.files;
        for (const file of files) {
          const { path } = file;
          const newPath = await cloudinaryImageUploadMethod(path);
          urls.push(newPath);
        }
        
        const product = new Product({ 
          name: req.body.name,
          productImages: urls.map( url => url.res ),
        });                   
 
     }
```

//error: the files is not iterable

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking `Ask Question`. You can also add a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above, you can use this pen for a simple javascript multiple image uploader: codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/pen/QgpyOK

Here's a very fancy uploader widget with a ton of options built-in: codepen.io/dzeitman/pen/EwgjJV

Hope this helps others trying to do something similar and just want to see something working.

Answer (score 0):

in input tag, you should write ... multiple.
and in post route, one should write

```
upload.array("image")
```

instead of

```
upload.single()
```

and in the schema file, you should define the image as an array of objects

```
i.e. image:[
{
URL: String,
filename: String
}
]
```