# Upload images with Cloudinary + MongoDB NextJS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, file-upload, next.js, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload multiple images for a product form. The API "works" but the first upload is always empty and never pushed to the product model of mongodb, also the API gets only the last image. When submitted the form, I get an empty array.
In addition, the cloudinary API gets the file when selected, not when submitted the entire form.

```
export default function NewProduct() {
  const initialState = {
    title: "",
    price: 0,
    description: "",
    content: "",
    images: [],
    category: "tortas",
  };

  const [product, setProduct] = useState(initialState);
  const { title, price, description, content, category } = product;

  console.log(product);

  const [image, setImage] = useState([]);

  // Other inputs
  const handleChangeInput = (e) => {
    setProduct({ ...product, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };


  // File uploader
  const handleUploadInput = async (e) => {
    const files = [...e.target.files];
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let file of files) {
      formData.append("file", file);
    }

    formData.append("upload_preset", "blabla");

    const res = await fetch(
      "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/blabla/image/upload",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      }
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    setImage([...image, data.secure_url]);
    setProduct({ ...product, images: image }); // Maybe Im missing something around here
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await createProduct();
  };

  //   const validate = () => {
  //     if(!title || !price || !description || !content) return
  //   }

  const createProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/products", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(product),
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

// The input
   <input type="file" onChange={handleUploadInput}  multiple accept="image/*"   />
```

Comment: The Cloudinary Upload API only supports a single file upload at a time, but it does have a high concurrency rate, so you can use multi-threads to upload many files at once. You can also use asynchronous calls, and tell Cloudinary to do the upload in the background by adding the 'async' parameter and setting it to 'true'. You may take a look at the recommendation here (node js example): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62142940/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-cloudinary